# Ionic input format

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an application in Ionic and use an input form field for my calculations.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="data" step="0.01">
```

However if I update the data with the value 100.10 the input box shows 100.1

I want to format the value in the input field so it always shows 2 decimals (100.1**0**).

I have tried using filters, but they only work when I change the input to type "text". I want to use a type="number" because this only shows the numeric keyboard.

I have also tried:

```
parseFloat(""+data.toFixed(2))
```

but this also shows 100.1

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Ionic, you get to use Angular. And in Angular you can do this simply like this:

```
{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}
```

So, if in your case you have a variable `data`and you would do it like this:

```
{{data | number : 2}}
```

More information in the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number).

Comment: This does not work. This is for labels and normal text. I want the text in the actual input field to show 100.10

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: And also - a plunker or CodePen with the exact example would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the type of the input, which is `number`. If you change it to `text` will solve the problem.

Or just remove the `parseFloat` from `data.toFixed(2)`. This way it will go as text to the form, with the trailing 0.

Comment: 'I have tried using filters, but they only work when I change the input to type "text". I want to use a type="number" because this only shows the numeric keyboard.'